# Making a function to change a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pypdf

I want to create a function that checks if a string variable contains ".pdf" at the end and if not, to add it to the variable. When I run this, the output_name does not change. It works outside of a function just fine but I want to create a function so I don't repeat myself. Thanks for the help!

```
def check(output_name):
    if ".pdf" not in output_name:
        output_name += ".pdf"
    else:
        return None

output_name = "sample"
check(output_name)
print(output_name)
```

Comment: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](//stackoverflow.com/a/986145)

Comment: `output_name = output_name if output_name.endswith('.pdf') else output_name+'.pdf'`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check_ext(x):
    return x if x[-4:] == ".pdf" else x+".pdf"
```

This could be also a good solution, as referenced above by @Chris_Rands

```
def check_ext1(str):
    return str if str.endswith(".pdf") else str+".pdf"
```

Output

```py
st= "string_variable"
print(check_ext(st))   # string_variable.pdf
print(check_ext1(st))  # string_variable.pdf
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's not a good answer since he wants by reference and not using a return statement. Just like in the @JohnnyMopp provided.

Comment: @Raphael Well tough, Python doesn’t *do* by reference, and even if it’s possible to circumvent it, this would be a *bad* solution. This answer provides the *correct* solution.

Comment: @ I know. But the answer is incomplete. You can change a list in a function by reference only, without returning it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145

Comment: @Raphael No. That is simply not a good solution. Mentioning here doesn’t make this answer better, on the contrary. Don’t teach bad code just to stay literal to what was asked, focus on teaching good code instead.

Comment: I agree, but I still think the answer is incomplete. He should explain that the string can't change by reference since it's immutable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Note edit is based on recommendation from the comment)

```
def check(output_name):

    if not output_name.endswith(".pdf"): 
        return output_name + ".pdf"

output_name = "sample.pdf"    
print(check(output_name))
print(output_name)
```

This line (`output_name += ".pdf"`) runs but you don't get anything because you didn't tell the function to return it. And you can't alter a variable in a function without an extra effort. Read about scopes.

If you really don't want the function returning anything or you want the variable to be alter by the function do this: WARNING => This is a bad practice!

```
output_name = "sample.pdf"

def check():
    global output_name  

    if not output_name.endswith(".pdf"): output_name += ".pdf"


check()
print(output_name)
```

Comment: Using `if …: pass` is convoluted and unnecessary. You could simply write `if not output_name.endswith(".pdf"): output_name += ".pdf"`. Besides that this answer doesn’t really add anything over existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

> **Method 1:** based on your code.

You have almost found the solution. Here, I refactor your code to make it work.

```
def check(output_name):
    if ".pdf" not in output_name:
        output_name += ".pdf"
    return output_name


output_name = "sample"
result = check(output_name)
print(result) # sample.pdf
```

> **Method 2:** base on the string method *endswith*

Here is a simple way to achieve your goal by using the *str* method *endswith*.

```
def check(output_name):
    if not output_name.endswith('.pdf'):
        output_name = output_name + ".pdf"
    return output_name

output_name = "sample"
result = check(output_name)
print(result) # sample.pdf
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest the following solution

```
def filename_editor():
    global output_name
    if ".pdf" not in output_name:
        output_name += ".pdf"

    global input_name
    if ".pdf" not in input_name:
        input_name += ".pdf"
```